# Exporting database from development to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm using the gem yaml_db to export my Postgres development database to production, which is on a virtual machine where my Ruby on Rails app is.

I'm using `rake db:data:dump RAILS_ENV=development` to create data.yml and `rake db:data:load RAILS_ENV=production`to import the data, but I'm getting erros in importing.

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: DELETE FROM "improvement_actions"

PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR:  cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
DETAIL:  Table "comments" references "improvement_actions".
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Or is there another method to export my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because there your database has foreign keys, which yaml_db doesn't support.

I think the easiest solution is to export your development database using `pg_dump` with the `--disable-triggers` flag and import it to your production database using `pg_restore`.

However, if you really want to use yaml_db, a [rather complicated solution has been documented](https://tovodeverett.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/making-yaml_db-work-with-schema_plus-constraints/). The heart of that solution is to

- make all of your foreign keys `deferrable initially immediate` if they aren't already. The documented solution uses the schema_plus gem, or you could do it in Postgres.
- monkey-patch yaml_db's `SerializationHelper::Base#load` to defer all constraints during each loading transaction with `set constraints all deferred;`
- monkey-patch yaml_db's `SerializationHelper::Base#truncate_table` to truncate tables by attempting to truncate as usual (which is not allowed on a table that has delayed triggers) and deleting if the truncation fails.

Comment: i just tried with yaml because I saw it on some tutorial. With pg_dump and pg_restore, how can I do that between my localhost and my virtual machine?

Comment: Exact details depend on the host, of course, but in general you would use scp to copy the dump to your VM, use ssh to log in to the VM, and run pg_restore there.

Comment: If the database that your VM uses is directly accessible from your development machine, you could run pg_restore on your laptop and point it at the VM's database. That database might not be accessible from outside for security reasons, however.